# What is the risk of using SHA1 in PGP email signatures?

Tags: email, pgp, sha

SHA-1 is being phased out by a lot of major companies due to vulnerabilities.
For example [Chrome no longer considers it safe for public web PKI.](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ca/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html)

Is it insecure to use SHA-1 for PGP email signatures?

Comment: Depends on what you are protecting in the e-mail.
Depends if your e-mail must be compliant with specific encryption standards.
Depends... need more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no practical attacks on SHA-1 yet. Experts estimate that SHA-1 attacks will start to appear around 2018.

As you have correctly pointed out, companies like Google and Microsoft have already taken action and are replacing SHA-1 with newer and safer standards:

> Microsoft is recommending that customers and CA’s stop using SHA-1 for cryptographic applications, including use in SSL/TLS and code signing. Microsoft Security Advisory 2880823 has been released along with the policy announcement that Microsoft will stop recognizing the validity of SHA-1 based certificates after 2016.

The recommendation is to move to SHA-2. So you'll have to reconfigure your PGP software to use another hash function, but the basic working principle of PGP will remain the same.

Comment: SHA-1 attacks rely on collisions.  The first wave (~2018) will involve brute forcing _two_ pieces of data such that they have the same hash.  Finding a second piece of data to match an original (e.g. from a PGP signature) is significantly harder and likely won't be feasible until quite a while later.  So from a PGP signing or encrypting context, there shouldn't be much concern.

Comment: @AdamKatz It can absolutely be an issue when signing: it's not that uncommon to use PGP to sign things received from others, which is a classic example of a collision vector.

Comment: The experts were fairly close, the first published, actual SHA-1 attack published 2017-02-23: https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html